# Setting onclick on parent results on parent executing onclick without intention Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a layout which I dont think its necessary to post here. But its basically a parent div with a very small width and height that stays on bottom right of a page, if clicked on it, it enlarges width and height.

Here where I had issue:

The parent contains onclick, if its click, it then change its size as well as disabling its onclick and adding onclick to an image, which is a button to minimise the parent div to its original size.

If the image is clicked then again, I disable the onclick on the image and add onclick on the main parent. However Javascript is executing onclick on the parent as it thinks its been clicked, since the image is inside the parent.

To fix this issue I had to set a setTimeout to add the onclick to the parent, that solved the issue, but is there a better way, and why does that happen?

Tahnks

```
function adjust_window_displayed(el, main_el){
var val = el.value;
var img_el = document.getElementById("img_envelope");
if(val === "true"){
    document.getElementById("display_mail_info").style.display = "block";
    img_el.src = "https://co.uk/minimise.png";
    img_el.style.cursor = "pointer";
    main_el.style.cursor = "default";
    main_el.onclick = function () {
      return false;
    };
    el.value = "false";
    img_el.onclick = function () {
        adjust_window_displayed(el, main_el);
        console.log("first");
    };
    console.log("first " + main_el.className);
}else{
    document.getElementById("display_mail_info").style.display = "none";
    img_el.src = "https://dco.uk/envelope.png";
    img_el.style.cursor = "default";
    main_el.style.cursor = "pointer";
    el.value = "true";
    img_el.onclick = function () {
        return false;
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
        main_el.onclick = function () {
            adjust_window_displayed(el, main_el);
            console.log("sec");
        };
    }, 700);
    console.log("second " + main_el.className);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is due to the event bubble, when you click on the `<img>` the click event fire once, then a second time for the parent, now if you don't handle that in your function properly it'll give you problems.

Now I have no idea how you're calling that function nor what parameters, you're passing to it, so i tried to reproduce the problem myself.

If you would assign the click event useing the `.onclick = function(){}`
you can use it to alter between the two, since you're using the same function.

```js
document.querySelector('#parent').onclick = lol;







function lol(e){
 var type = e.target.nodeName;
 if (type == "DIV") 
 {
  if (e.target.onclick)
  {
   alert('clicked parent');
   e.target.onclick = "";
   document.querySelector('#kid').onclick = lol;
  }
 }
 else if (type == "IMG") 
 { 
  if (e.target.onclick)
  {
   alert('clicked kid');
   e.target.onclick = "";
   document.querySelector('#parent').onclick = lol;
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
img{
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 <img id="kid">
</div>
```